# Scheduling a Delay Job on Heroku with a Worker Dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I'm currently using Heroku's scheduler to run a script. However, the time that the script takes to run is going to increase from a few milliseconds to a few minutes. I'm looking at using the delayed_job gem to push this process off to a Worker Dyno. I want to continue to run this script once-a-day, just offload it to the worker. My current rake task is:

```
desc "This task updates some stuff for you."
task :update_some_stuff => :environment do
  puts "Updating some stuff ..."
  SomeClass.new.process
  puts "... done."
end
```

Once the gem is installed, migration run, and worker dyno started, will the script just need to change to:

```
 desc "This task updates some stuff for you."
    task :update_some_stuff => :environment do
      puts "Updating some stuff ..."
      SomeClass.new.delay.process
      puts "... done."
    end
```

With this task still being a rake task scheduled by Heroku's Scheduler, is the only thing that needs to happen here the introduction of the `delay` method to put this in the Worker's queue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DJ is a very simple gem, and you should be able to see this working correctly locally by adding a record to your `delayed_jobs` table in your database.  With a worker running on Heroku everything should be fine.

Just make sure you have the following in your Procfile:

```
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

More information can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job